# Simple encode and decode pipeline with gstreamer?

Tags: gstreamer

I'm trying to create a simple gstreamer1-0 pipeline that encodes and decodes h264 a webcam feed hopefully using the most basic elements possible. I already have (theoretically) all standard, good, bad and ugly gstreamer libraries installed. I used the word "Theoretically" because I don't have root privileges and I have to request IT to download/install every single library I might need and it's quite a pain.

I've tried the following pipeline but it didn't work:

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src ! autovideoconvert ! x264enc bitrate=256 ! decodebin ! autovideosink
```

I get the following output:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
Redistribute latency...
Missing element: H.264 decoder
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0: Your GStreamer installation is missing a plug-in.
Additional debug info:
gstdecodebin2.c(3977): gst_decode_bin_expose (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0:
no suitable plugins found
Execution ended after 0:00:01.795803500
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Setting pipeline to READY ...
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

So according to that I'm missing a block to my plugin to decode h264 right?

Now I've read this [forum](http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/in-gstreamer-1-6-2-when-using-decodebin-plugin-it-return-quot-Missing-element-H-264-Constrained-Base-td4675235.html) and I've no idea how to install the decoder block. If somebody can explain to me how to do that in order to get that simple pipeline running?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You might be missing h264 decoder plugin. You can check it with

```
gst-inspect-1.0 | grep 264
```

The decoder that's generally used is `avdec_h264`

This will list the plugins related with h264. If you don't have any decoders you'll want to install gst-libav packages.

Comment: Yea, I tried that and I didn't see it... Most grateful for the avdec_h264 and gst-libav package information. I will look into that. Will avdec_h264 word with x264enc block or do I have to use the matching avdec_h264 encoding block?

EDIT: this is what I get when I do inspect: 
    x264:  x264enc: x264enc
    rtp:  rtph264depay: RTP H264 depayloader
    rtp:  rtph264pay: RTP H264 payloader
    videoparsersbad:  h264parse: H.264 parser
    typefindfunctions: video/x-h264: h264, x264, 264

Comment: Yes you're lacking a h264 decoder. avdec_h264 will work fine with x264enc. I guess gst-libav package has another encoder for h264 but x264enc is ok.

Comment: Awesome, many many thanks... I'll try it out and get back to you as soon as I can... btw, how do I select the answer? is it necessary if there's only one? xD

Comment: You're welcome. It's better to select the answer to let other people having same problems know that it worked for you even if there's only one answer. ( https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work )

Answer (score 2):

In centos 7, you can install it via yum:

```
sudo yum install -y http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/el/updates/7/x86_64/g/gstreamer1-libav-1.10.4-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

and then check it again:

```
gst-inspect-1.0 | grep 264
```

now you can see the decoders

Comment: by the way, check the version

Answer (score 1):

```sh
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc num-buffers=10 ! x264enc ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
```

Please note `videoconvert` is required to show the video.

Answer (score 0):

All encoders produce standard-compliant video stream, and all decoders can accept standard compliant encoded video stream. So, it does not matter which encoder/decoder combination you use. Any combination should work.